# Prevent a window from resizing

Tags: terminal, vim-windows

I nearly always have a terminal window open when I'm doing extensive editing in Vim. I've used `tnoremap` to set mappings for the three heights I want the terminal window to be able to take.

Unfortunately, when splitting a window or quitting a window, Vim resizes all windows (effectively doing a `^W=`). I want my terminal window to be exempt from all such resizing. If as a consequence all resizing except for adjusting the adjacent windows to close up the space is disabled, I can live with that.

How can I tell Vim to never resize my terminal window unless I explicitly request it? Better yet, in addition to my last question, is it possible to make my terminal window keep its size even when I issue `^W_`?

Answer (score 7):

In researching something else, I stumbled across the answer to this question:

```
set noequalalways
```